# Resolve CSS Line Wrapping in VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to learning coding and I'm trying to figure out how to set up VS Code so that it doesn't wrap HTML tags in CSS. I have Prettier installed and set as my default formatter. It won't allow more than one HTML tag on a single line in CSS and I can't figure out why.
[Screenshot of wrapping HTML tags in CSS doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brmCV.png)

Comment: Can you post an image or a code of how it looks like?

Comment: Just uploaded a screenshot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to un-wrap your code in the editor, just press `alt + z` in the file you want to (wrap-unwrap) the code.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working unfortunately. When I save and Prettier auto formats the doc it's still putting tags on their own line. I must be missing something?